# Can't update gradle plugin to 1.3.0-beta4 in Android Studio 1.3

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle, android-6.0-marshmallow, gradle-plugin

While exploring new API's and features shipped with Android "M", I came across new data binding framework. So, I followed step-by-step guide from [Android Authority](http://www.androidauthority.com/blu-life-one-review-615535/) and [Android Developer's](https://developer.android.com/tools/data-binding/guide.html) post to see this in action. To use data binding, project requires gradle plugin 1.3.0-beta4.But if I try to update, it gives me error something like this:

```
Error:(1, 0) Plugin is too old, please update to a more recent version,
or set ANDROID_DAILY_OVERRIDE environment variable to 
"c70732ebe5710634c90aa6755f18c037274b3dac".
```

Could someone explain me how to resolve this issue?

Comment: There's no need for the beta plugin, `1.3.0` has already been released.

Comment: But the docs says to use 1.3.0-beta4. At -least I should be able to update my plugin

Comment: The docs says to use `1.3.0-beta4` _or higher_ ;-) Since that page was written, 1.3.0 has been released, which is higher than `1.3.0-beta4`.

Comment: ohh. I didn't realized that. Thanx :)

Comment: Does this resolve your issue?

Comment: It works for me. Thanks for the time you saved @nhaarman.

Comment: yes, your solution helped me :)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments, you need to modify your gradle file to remove beta4 word, the new line should be like:

```
classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0"
```